# Possible methods of making detecting MAC addresses more straightforward?

Tags: linux, routing, wired-networking

For a little bit of background, I am a student computer technician and have spent quite a bit of time finding the ethernet MAC address of numerous devices so that they can be registered for use on campus internet. But, I want to make my life a little simpler and develop something, a small cli program perhaps, that can detect MAC addresses of the devices connected to a computer through the Ethernet port on it.

*It is important for you to notice that I am referring only to Ethernet MAC addresses, as in the MAC address assigned to the Ethernet port(s) of a device. This is not the same as the WiFi MAC address that is assigned to the WiFi card of a device, as it is a different, separate component.

*I only need to view the MAC address of only one device at a time, so no ethernet switches should be necessary.

I sometimes use a router when assisting people in getting the ethernet MAC address of devices, such as TVs, that is not listed anywhere in any menu on the device itself, nor on its stickers or packaging. I know that the router somehow detects the MAC address of whatever device is connected to it according to however it is connected to the router. What I would like to do is eliminate the router (despite how small and cute mine is), as I have to carry both the router and my laptop to make this work. I know that it is possible to turn a computer into a router, as I have done so before. I had to do so at a previous job in order to link a small local network of clustered computers (connected to a dumb switch) to our campus network, using the head node of the cluster as the router since it had 4 free Ethernet ports (it was a Linux cluster btw).

1) Since computers can be set up as routers, I'd like to set up my own as one (but preferably only temporarily via a CLI program) with the caveat that I want the connected device to be displayed in the terminal.

I used some kind of CLI command to set up the previously mentioned computer into a router, I'm sure at some point I'll recall what it was so I can use that software again so that is not much of an issue (unless you have a suggestion).

Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but I don't know a straightforward way of making my idea a reality as I have no idea where the MAC addresses detected are stored, or if there is a simple command I can use to print the MAC address detected by my computer once it is acting as a router.

Keep in mind that I prefer to do this all in Linux (I primarily use Debian, but am familiar with CentOS/SL), as my coworker actually might end up adapting my program to work on his own Raspberry Pi. This is why I want to make such a CLI program that I described earlier, since the Pi will only be used for that particular purpose if we succeed. No mouse, no keyboard, just a Pi with a screen that will show the MAC address of a device connectdd to its ethernet port. Windows implementations would be noted, but bear in mind I'd translate them to Linux anyway so do include as much detail as you can, please.

2) I'd like to know if it's possible to see MAC addresses beyond an Ethernet adapter. Let me explain the issue:

I ask becuse I have a Chromebook belonging to a family member that I might be able to keep. If I can, then I could possibly install Linux on and use it for testing, but it doesn't have an Ethernet port. I can get an Ethernet adapter, but in my experience I know that when you connect a device to a campus network with an Ethernet adapter in between (eg. Using a computer with an adapter to connect to campus Ethernet), the MAC address of the Ethernet adapter is what is seen first by the network (any time I contact the campus network operation center, they can tell me the MAC address of the adapter connected to the Ethernet port in a room. I won't be back in contact with them anytime soon, I'd ask them if I were).

So, I assume that if I turned a laptop into a router, I might run into the issue where it might see the MAC address of the adapter connected to it instead of the device on the other end of that adapter. So, IF it is possible to "see" past the adapter, how is it possible? I am very ignorant about the scope of commands like arp and trace route, although I've had to use them in only a few situations. But, I do wonder if I am on the right track thinking that there may be a way for a router to view the MAC addresses on the path to a device. And this is all assuming that it is possible to turn a computer that doesn't have an Ethernet port into a router, as it is way out of my scope of knowledge.

Also, there is a possibility that my coworker and I are just overlooking something terribly simple. So lastly:

3) If you have any rugged-brained ideas, do let me know. I'm willing to try other things, especially a more simplistic approach to what we are trying to implement.

Comment: Have you looked at Advanced IP Scanner (Famatech and Free). This can scan a Class C network and gives you the information you are asking for. It will pick up both wired and wireless devices. It also gives you the device name to help sort it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is important for you to notice that I am referring only to Ethernet MAC addresses, as in the MAC address assigned to the Ethernet port(s) of a device. This is not the same as the WiFi MAC address that is assigned to the WiFi card of a device, as it is a different, separate component.

It is important to notice that as long as Wi-Fi-connected devices are bridged to the same network as Ethernet-connected devices, it is impossible to distinguish their MAC addresses just by examining the network state, as they behave in exactly the same way. You can only distinguish them by looking at access point "connected device" lists, or from information shown by the device itself.

> I know that the router somehow detects the MAC address of whatever device is connected to it according to however it is connected to the router.

Most routers show you all addresses registered in the DHCP lease table. Some also combine this list with addresses kept in the ARP cache / ICMPv6 ND cache.

Both methods require the device to initiate the conversation, so to speak. The router cannot actually 'probe' what's on the other end of the wire.

> I want to make such a CLI program that I described earlier, since the Pi will only be used for that particular purpose if we succeed. No mouse, no keyboard, just a Pi with a screen that will show the MAC address of a device connectdd to its ethernet port.

For most devices that's easy to do by just capturing all packets seen on the Ethernet interface using tcpdump. Usually the device will send things like DHCP queries, ICMPv6 NAs, IGMP or MLD registrations, unsolicited ARPs, and such. You can capture all of them and grab the source address.

But as already mentioned – if the device sends no packets at all when connected, then there's no way to learn its MAC address either. (Ethernet does not require any particular L2 handshake once connected. DHCP is merely common, not mandatory.)

> So, I assume that if I turned a laptop into a router, I might run into the issue where it might see the MAC address of the adapter connected to it instead of the device on the other end of that adapter.

No, it doesn't usually work like that. USB-connected Ethernet adapters behave the same way as "normal" built-in or PCI-connected ports – they are not standalone network devices; instead the computer is fully in control of what Ethernet frames are sent and received.

So when the laptop is receiving Ethernet frames over the USB adapter, it will always see the original source MAC.

> I can get an Ethernet adapter, but in my experience I know that when you connect a device to a campus network with an Ethernet adapter in between (eg. Using a computer with an adapter to connect to campus Ethernet), the MAC address of the Ethernet adapter is what is seen first by the network [...] So, IF it is possible to "see" past the adapter, how is it possible?

That's true, but it has nothing to do with the adapter "hiding" MAC addresses.

Note that in one paragraph, you're talking about how your laptop *sees* packets coming from the network. But in another paragraph, you're talking about how your laptop is seen *by* the network.

With both USB and built-in Ethernet ports, the computer is fully in control over what Ethernet frames it sends, including the "source MAC" address. However, the computer itself *does not have* a MAC address assigned to it – they always come from the Ethernet adapter. (Even if it were a built-in Ethernet port, the MAC address seen by the network would still be coming from its integrated Ethernet chip, and not from the computer as a whole.)

As a result, it is perfectly normal that the *network* sees the USB adapter's MAC address, because that's where the address comes from in the first place. The USB adapter isn't really "hiding" the true MAC address from the network, because there *is* no "true" address other than the one provided by the adapter itself.

And likewise, the *laptop* will see incoming packets exactly as they come – the USB adapter is not going to do anything to hide the MAC addresses in received packets.

*(Side note: There are exceptions to the "computers don't have MACs" rule. It is possible, and apparently very common on 'embedded' SoCs, that there's no MAC baked into the Ethernet adapter, and it's instead provided through other sources such as bootloader config.)*

> And this is all assuming that it is possible to turn a computer that doesn't have an Ethernet port into a router, as it is way out of my scope of knowledge

If you connect a USB-Ethernet adapter to a computer, then *it has an Ethernet port.* Doesn't matter whether it's attached via USB or via PCI, it works at the same level.

Any computer can be a router, even if it has no Ethernet at all – the only requirement for "being a router" is to connect two IP subnets. For example, if you have a laptop with e.g. Wi-Fi plus a virtual machine network, it'll also act as a router for the VMs.

> 1) Since computers can be set up as routers, I'd like to set up my own as one (but preferably only temporarily via a CLI program) with the caveat that I want the connected device to be displayed in the terminal.
>
> I used some kind of CLI command to set up the previously mentioned computer into a router, I'm sure at some point I'll recall what it was so I can use that software again so that is not much of an issue (unless you have a suggestion).

But that's all irrelevant, because **your computer does not need to be a router** in order to know the attached devices' MACs. The information sources mentioned above – DHCP leases and ARP cache – are merely common in routers, but not exclusive to routers, and not actually a part of IP routing as such.

Any IP-speaking device will have an ARP cache, and any computer can act as a DHCP server even if it won't actually do any routing at all. For example, you can install *dnsmasq* on your laptop, point it at any Ethernet port, and there you have a DHCP server that'll answer lease requests from any connected device.

For example, here's my usual "instant DHCP" command:

```
sudo dnsmasq --no-daemon --conf-file=/dev/null --no-hosts --port=0 \
             --interface=eth0 --bind-dynamic \
             --dhcp-range=192.168.1.1,192.168.1.254,255.255.255.0,1h \
             --dhcp-option=option:dns-server,8.8.8.8
```

That's it. As soon as you connect a device to eth0, *if* that device is set up to use DHCP, it'll show up in the dnsmasq output. (And it'll be issued an IP address that your laptop can reach, too.) You *can* combine this with actual IP routing (and probably NAT/masquerading), but you don't need to.

However, you **don't even need actual DHCP service** either. If the connected device wants to use DHCP, it will be sending the DHCP queries no matter what – and you can just pick out the origin address from packet-capture tools such as `tcpdump`.

tl;dr: See spiff's post.

Comment: Unintentionally tapped the CW checkbox while posting, but oh well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tcpdump` to sniff all packets received on your Ethernet interface, and filter out (ignore) all the ones that come from your own MAC address. Then while `tcpdump` is running, plug in your target device directly into your Ethernet interface. Most devices broadcast some ARP and DHCP and other traffic when their Ethernet link first comes up, so you should expect to see some packets when you first connect the Ethernet cable.

The nice thing about this solution is you don't even have to turn your Ubuntu box into any kind of router or bridge to do this. All you need is a working Ethernet interface that is available for this use.

So, let's say your Ubuntu box's Ethernet interface is eth0 and has MAC address "00:11:22:33:44:55". You could run a command something like this:

```
sudo tcpdump -nei eth0 'not ether src 00:11:22:33:44:55' | awk '{print $2}'
```

That command will print just the source MAC address of every packet received on eth0. You'll probably see several packets from the target device, so you'll probably see several copies of the same MAC address. You can hit Ctrl-C to exit the command. You can probably improve this script to, say, take a single MAC address from the output and copy it to the clipboard, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

If your target device does NOT send packets when its Ethernet link first comes up, try rebooting it. Most devices send packets as they boot.